# iOS Reminders app can set reminders based on a particular date

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, reminders

if I choose the default Reminders app to remind me something on a day (for example Feb-10) AND at a location it says something like "On Feb-10 your location based reminder will be active".

So it can setup a location based reminder even in the background, **on a particular date?**

This is really interesting, and I want to know how is this possible, is there some trick or it's just because Apple give unlimited power to their stock apps?

P.S - I already know how to setup location-based reminders.

Answer (score 2):

Its no big deal. This techniques is called `GeoFencing`. You can do it too. [Apple Location framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) provides some interesting APIs for this purpose.

Try to use the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
```

What these delegate methods give you is a easy way to set local notification on a iOS device. So for example you can provide an interface where a user wants to be notified about something when he enters a `region`. The definition of `region` is nothing but latitude, longitude with a radius defined. Ex. when you enter a certain region on your way to work you can set a reminder to drop off laundry. etc.
It's all actually pretty easy...

To add a little bit more. There are 2 sides to this. First setting the notification, next is consuming or showing the notification. Setting the notification is a straightforward user's current location capture. While doing tell locationManager to monitor this region. When the user enters this region (you could have a date as further filtering criteria) then alert the user.

All this will work even if your app is running in background or closed. iOS will take care of this.

[[more code here]](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/get-started-geofencing-ios)

Comment: Thanks Srikar, your help is very much appreciated. But I already know how to geofence a certain region, I don't know how to start geofencing it based on a particular date?

Comment: Aah, to set on a particular date simply use localNotifications. Its a cinch. This link provides code that you can directly use. Note that   iOS Reminder App uses a OR relationship. i.e. remind you on a DATE or when ENTERING/EXITING a region. With the approach I outlined you can accomplish this. http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/